# Polymer - two browsers on same machine

Tags: polymer-1.0

I noticed this in my custom app, but it applies to the Polymer starter kit as well. I have two browsers open, Chrome and Firefox, and a click on one browser in my Polymer app affects the other.

Why?

How?!!

(Chrome on left, Firefox on right. Clicking in Firefox affects Chrome!)
[image: Gif of this happening]

**Edit:** And my phone?!!

Comment: BrowserSync most likely

Answer (score 1):

This was due to how the page was served. Polymer Starter Kit has a gulp file setup to server and auto-reload the pages. Works great! But I guess it also keeps things perfectly in sync. Great for development : )

Serving with something else ([live-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server)) allowed the app to function as expected.

**Edit:** As @chillitom mentioned in the comments, it was BrowserSync. When I start using `gulp serve` I see this:

```
[PSK] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:5000
    External: http://192.168.1.107:5000
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3002
 UI External: http://192.168.1.107:3002
 --------------------------------------
```

Going to `http://localhost:3002` allowed me to change browser sync options, and that "fixed" this as well.